# Passing arguments to a view in a different bundle - symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm creating a control panel application that has a base bundle with some basic functionality and specific bundles for advanced and specific functionality.

for example the base bundle handles user authentication and holds all the template assets and other bundles add functionalities to config different parts of the operating system.

I need to be able to add menu links in the layout of the base bundle to each of the other bundles. and I prefer to do it in each bundles configuration so I can mix and match features for different clients.

I read all about Compiler Passes, Extensions and dependency injection with no luck. is there correct of doing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone has a similar problem, here is how I achieved this:

I created a service in my BaseBundle that implements the __get , __set, __isset and __unset magic methods and has an extra append method. it stores variables in a static variable inside the class.
I then added Listeners to all my bundles :

```
namespace Mbs\OtherBundle\Listener;

use Mbs\BaseBundle\Services\GlobalVars;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

class ControllerListener
{
    protected $_global_vars;

    public function __construct(GlobalVars $global_vars)
    {
        $this->_global_vars = $global_vars;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $this->_global_vars->append('bundles', 'mbs.other');
    }
}
```

This is my services.yml for one of the bundles. GlobalVars is the class I mentioned earlier.

```
services:
    mbs.base_controller_listener:
        class: Mbs\OtherBundle\Listener\ControllerListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
        arguments:  [ @mbs.global_vars ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Twig this should do the trick...

```
{% render "DifferentBundle:ControllerName:functionalityName" with {'argument_name': 3} %}
```

You should have a `functionalityNameAction` method in your DifferentBundle controller for this to work.

Take a look at the [Creating and using Templates - Embedding Controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) section in the doc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how many bundles need to insert links menu. I want other bundles to add links to the base bundle.

Comment: I think that it's not possible. You will need to embed the other bundles links into your base bundle instead.